# Use PHP classes on a ma

Tags: php, parse-platform

I'm new to PHP and I need to use some classes from an external library in my project.

My .php file, `SMMain.php` is in `/Library/WebServer/Documents` directory on my Mac. I placed the classes from the outside library right there next to it. All of these files are from the `namespace Parse;`. Some of the classes are in a directory called `Internal`.

No matter what `require_once` I try I get errors that the files are not found. Here's what I tried:

```
require_once('\Internal\Encodable.php');
```

produces this error:

```
Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '\Internal\Encodable.php' (include_path='.:') in /Library/WebServer/Documents/SMMain.php on line 13
```

Next try:

```
require_once('/Internal/Encodable.php');
```

produces this:

```
Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '.php' (include_path='.:') in /Library/WebServer/Documents/SMMain.php on line 7
```

I also tried:

```
require_once(realpath($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]) .'/Internal/Encodable.php');
```

Gives no error for the `/Internal/Encodable` file, but this produces another error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'ParseObject' not found in /Library/WebServer/Documents/SMMain.php on line 24
```

`ParseObject.php` is in the root directory together with my `SMMain.php`. So I tried requiring it like this:

```
require_once(realpath($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]) . '/ParseObject.php');
```

which gives this error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'ParseObject' not found in /Library/WebServer/Documents/SMMain.php on line 24
```

and if I try this:

```
require_once(realpath($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]) . 'ParseObject.php');
```

the error is:

```
Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '/Library/WebServer/DocumentsParseObject.php' (include_path='.:') in /Library/WebServer/Documents/SMMain.php on line 17
```

So what's the solution?

Comment: `require_once` is load the file, nothing else, so namespaces are irrelevant here.

Comment: OK but what should I do?

Comment: try to use `require_once('../../../Internal\Encodable.php');` Let's say, `echo getcwd();` what is show you your current directory. Or remove the relpath. `require_once($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] .'/Internal/Encodable.php');`

Comment: require_once deals with filesystem paths, and does not deal with namespaces. you need to figure out the path of your library as it exists on the file system, and then either use an absolute `/path/to/your/script.php` or relative `../somewhere/whatever/script.php`

Answer (score 0):

Use `require_once($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] .'/Internal/Encodable.php');` if the Internal directory is under the server document root and the Encodable.php is in there.

You can use the `echo getcwd();` to see, where is the current working directory.

I am always doing that, when i call my index.php file (it handles all other files), to determinate, where is my base path, and store it in a constant. So lately, i will always include files with that path as an absolute path.

Comment: and what should I do with ParseObject.php, which is in the root directory?

Comment: require_once($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] .'ParseObject.php'); Let's listen to the dependecy, if it has.